# pandas groupby mean sorting by ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset

I have a large data set : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-07-19/technology.csv

here is the head of the dataset:
[head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBIzc.png)

I have to grouped this dataset by the variables and taken the averages of each country's technology adoption with this:

```
df.groupby(['variable','iso3c'])[['value']].mean()
```

here is the output

```
                           value
variable     iso3c              
BCG          AFG       45.763158
             AGO       56.648649
             ALB       93.875000
             ARE       86.650000
             ARG       93.700000
...                          ...
visitorrooms VNM    46920.636364
             YEM     5527.280000
             ZAF    48431.850000
             ZMB     3518.000000
             ZWE     4696.440000
```

Now, I want to sort within the variables by largest values to smallest. I thought of doing this:

```
df.groupby(['variable','iso3c'])[['value']].mean().sort_values(['variable','value'])
```

but this is the output

```
                           value
variable     iso3c              
BCG          SWE    1.722500e+01
             SOM    3.812500e+01
             AFG    4.576316e+01
             TCD    4.586111e+01
             ETH    5.141026e+01
...                          ...
visitorrooms ESP    5.755948e+05
             JPN    6.531027e+05
             DEU    7.400641e+05
             ITA    9.286496e+05
             USA    3.040499e+06

[16933 rows x 1 columns]
```

I have no idea what happens to the values here. How do I fix this?

Comment: looks correct to me. It's just a different representation. You can chain that with `.round(3)` to see the decimal representation.

Comment: `sort_values(['variable','value'], ascending=[True, False])` to sort variables lexicographically  and values from largest to smallest

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have a large variance in the values so it's using exp() form.

Option 1: You can  chain your sort_values() with a round(x) where x is the number of significant digits you want.

Option 2: [Set the pandas precision option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html#number-formatting) to a form you find more comfortable to work with.

Comment: Oops, thanks... I am dumb lol

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-07-19/technology.csv')

# Data Pre-Process
df_v2 = df.groupby(['variable','iso3c'])['value'].mean().reset_index()
df_v2.sort_values(['variable','value'],ascending=[True, False]  ,inplace=True)

# Showing Output
df_v2
```

Hi Brother,

I have attached the code for you, if you have any question please let me know

Thanks
Leon